# I get two icons instead of one when adding some apps to the favourites

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I get this weird problem when I try to add cheese app and videos app and terminal to the favourites (Ubuntu dock) and both of the icons are functioning.
Why is this happening?

I am running brand new installation of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I have many apps in dock but cheese has two icons.

[image: Screenshot]

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps
['firefox.desktop', 'thunderbird.desktop', 'org.gnome.Software.desktop', 'nemo.desktop', 'update-manager.desktop', 'gnome-control-center.desktop', 'org.gnome.Screenshot.desktop', 'org.gnome.Terminal.desktop', 'synaptic.desktop', 'org.gnome.Cheese.desktop']
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of the following command in Terminal: `gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps`.

Comment: I will try to do this

Comment: No !! the second icon disappeared after re-logging in. and sorry for deleting the screenshot, I wanted to update it because I change the dock so often. Also I noticed the same issue with a live USB stick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps`, it seems it's just a graphical glitch. Simply logging out and reloggin-in should fix it.

As a simple alternative of re-logging in all the time, you may restart the GNOME shell instead. To do that, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then type `r`, and finally press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: It works ! thank you but I really want to report the issue cause it's annoying.